# Open3d - toggle on and off point cloud

Tags: open3d

Is there a way I can toggle on and off one of the point clouds?
I'm visualizing two point clouds but want to toggle on and off one of them to check how each point cloud is being visualized.
Does Open3d have any functions that can be used to implement this?

I'm using a stereo camera (zed-m) that takes photos from the left and right camera. It also has a depth image. I want to un-project two images into 3d point clouds and compare between 1. only left point cloud 2. only right point cloud 3. both point clouds by toggling on and off each point cloud.

Thanks!